# Class object overlapping

Tags: javascript, class, object, prototype

im still trying to learn and im trying to make a group of actors be added to a movie class, i made it work but i still have problems because if you add another actor the last one dissappears, i tried with a loop but i could do nothing.

```js
class Movie {
    constructor(title,year,duration){
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    addCast(actors){
        this.actors = actors
    }
}     
class Actor {
    constructor(name,age)
    {  
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

const terminator = new Movie('Terminator I', 1985, 60);
const arnold = new Actor('Arnold Schwarzenegger', 50);
const otherCast = [
    new Actor('Paul Winfield', 50),
    new Actor('Michael Biehn', 50),
    new Actor('Linda Hamilton', 50)
];
//From here it can not be modified
    let movieOne = new Movie("Kong","2018","2h30m");
    let movieTwo = new Movie("Joker","2019","2h03m");
    let movieThree = new Movie("John Wick 3", "2019", "1h49m");
    terminator.addCast(arnold);
    terminator.addCast(otherCast);
//To here it can not be modified
    console.log({movieOne,movieTwo,movieThree,terminator});
```

See? Arnold should be in the actors too but it isnt! Thanks for the help in advance.

Another thing, this is for an excercise and i can not modify the lines i commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
addCast(actors){
    this.actors = actors
}
```

This does not *add* the passed actor array to the `actors` on the instance - it *replaces* the instance's `actors` with the passed argument. Calling `addCast` will result in whatever previously existed on `actors` being lost.

To help reduce bugs, it can help to name methods appropriately - for logic like this, I'd call it `setCast`, not `addCast`.

If you want to add onto the end of the existing cast, and you're not sure whether the argument will be a single actor to add or an array of actors to add, use:

```
  addCast(actorOrActors) {
    if (Array.isArray(actorOrActors)) {
      this.actors.push(...actorOrActors);
    } else {
      this.actors.push(actorOrActors);
    }
  }
```

```js
class Movie {
  constructor(title, year, duration) {
    this.title = title;
    this.year = year;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.actors = [];
  }

  addCast(actorOrActors) {
    if (Array.isArray(actorOrActors)) {
      this.actors.push(...actorOrActors);
    } else {
      this.actors.push(actorOrActors);
    }
  }
}
class Actor {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

const terminator = new Movie('Terminator I', 1985, 60);
const arnold = new Actor('Arnold Schwarzenegger', 50);
const otherCast = [
  new Actor('Paul Winfield', 50),
  new Actor('Michael Biehn', 50),
  new Actor('Linda Hamilton', 50)
];
//From here it can not be modified
let movieOne = new Movie("Kong", "2018", "2h30m");
let movieTwo = new Movie("Joker", "2019", "2h03m");
let movieThree = new Movie("John Wick 3", "2019", "1h49m");
terminator.addCast(arnold);
terminator.addCast(otherCast);
//To here it can not be modified
console.log({
  movieOne,
  movieTwo,
  movieThree,
  terminator
});
```

Comment: Hi, im probably doing something very obvious wrong but im new. You changed the param name in order to avoid confusion with the word actors right?
Then i tried just brute copy pasting your code but i got i cannot read the property push of undefined at 64 and 89 (adding arnold), is it something im losing here?

Comment: See the live snippet in the answer, it works as desired - make sure to initialize `this.actors` to the empty array in the constructor, so that calls to `addCast` push to that array instead of replacing it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your addCast() method, each time you call it, you are replacing the previous value instead of appending it

Comment: Yes, you are rigth but i dont know how to do it properly. How is this method of adding instead of overlapping an object is named?

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite arnold with your second addActors call.
Only add one actor at a time to an array of actors.

```
class Movie {
constructor(title,year,duration){
    this.title = title;
    this.year = year;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.actors = [];
}


addCast(actor){
    this.actors.push(actor);
}

terminator.addCast(arnold);
terminator.addCast(otherCast[0]);
terminator.addCast(otherCast[1]);
terminator.addCast(otherCast[2]);
```